# Using a Visual Sourcesafe login with no password

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

We use SourceSafe to prevent accidents, not fraud. Our SourceSafe User names are the same as our Windows user names, and none of our SourceSafe accounts (not even Admin) have a password. When we log in to SourceSafe, the login dialog doesn't even have a space for a password.

A few days ago, my co-worker accidentally checked out a file and then left for the day. I needed to make a change to the file and then check it in. My first attempt to solve this problem was to log in to SourceSafe with her UserID, so that I could "Undo check-out". (This is the first time I ever tried to do this.) However, when I tried to do this, a different login dialog appeared, asking me for the UserID and password. I left the password field blank and pressed OK, but then error message displayed: "Invalid password".

Eventually I figured out that I could log in as "Admin" with no password, and that Admin is able to Undo Checkout for any user.

My account also does not have a password, and yet my co-worker is not able to log in as me unless she is logged in to my Windows account.

My question is, why did this happen? Is there any way to set up several user accounts (other than Admin), so that anyone can log in to them without a password?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following environment variables:

```
SSUSER - username
SSPWD - password
```

[More](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yw05w28c%28VS.80%29.aspx) and [more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181062%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) info.

Comment: Two reasons that doesn't help: (1)You can't set an environmental variable to the empty string; the closest you can do is set it to a single space. (2)It still brings up the login dialog (with password), and changing the password to the empty string still fails.